# cannot centrally administer user profile in wink2003

Tags: users, roaming-profile

I have created one shared folder to store domain user roaming profile on a profile server. The issue is only the  user has the right to open the user profile folder on a profile server, not even the domain administrator and the local server administrator can open it.This is means I have to manually add myself in every of the user profile to administer it.Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it sounds like you are looking for would be control by this group policy which allows you to add permissions to profiles.

> **Computer Configuration\Administrative
>   Templates\System\User profiles\Add the
>   administrators security group to
>   roaming user profiles**
>
> This setting adds the administrator
>   security group to the roaming user
>   profile share.
>
> Once an administrator has configured a
>   users´ roaming profile, the profile
>   will be created at the user´s next
>   login. The profile is created at the
>   location that is specified by the
>   administrator.
>
> For the Windows 2000 Professional and
>   Windows XP Professional operating
>   systems, the default file permissions
>   for the newly generated profile are
>   full control, or read and write access
>   for the user, and no file access for
>   the administrators group.
>
> By configuring this setting, you can
>   alter this behavior.
>
> If you enable this setting, the
>   administrator group is also given full
>   control to the user´s profile folder.

Comment: +1. Just a note that enabling this option will affect NEW profiles but will not add the Administrators group to the permissions of existing profiles.